# how to index a flattened mgrid array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

a= [np.ndarray.flatten(res) for res in np.mgrid[0:1:6j, 0:1:6j]]

## how do you index the a array

I have researched many other resources and I have tried using multiple solutions but to no avail.
I think slicing may be the answer and I have tried multiple slicing solutions but again have not been able to index the array

This is a Python statement and I am trying to create a sub array of certain elements of the a array

Comment: What happens when you index it?

Comment: I kept getting errors - mostly that I was trying to use tuple list to access the array or out of bounds script etc.

Comment: I have got the following code to work
    a= [np.ndarray.flatten(res) for res in np.mgrid[0:1:6j, 0:1:6j]]
    sub_array0 = resolution[0]
    sub_array1 = resolution[1]
Then I combine the arrays (o and 1) to get the final result.
I am sure the is a cleaner way